# Woocommerce, сортировка по имени не работает

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Использую нижеприведённый код для сортировки товаров по имени.
Названия товаров начинаются на цифру, дальше буквы.
Но проблема в том, что один товар сортируется неправильно, получается как-то так при сортировке по asc:

23 tovar name
33 tovar name
45 tovar name
62 tovar name
35 tovar name
т.е. один товар `35 tovar name` всегда не на своём месте,при сортировке по убыванию он находится в самом начале, а при сортировке по возрастанию, он самый последний.
Из-за чего это может быть?

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'wh_catalog_ordering_args');
function wh_catalog_ordering_args($args) {
    global $wp_query;
    if (isset($_GET['orderby'])) {
        switch ($_GET['orderby']) {
            case 'name-asc' :
                $args['order'] = 'ASC';
                $args['meta_key'] = '';
                $args['orderby'] = 'name';
                break;
            case 'name-desc' :
                $args['order'] = 'DESC';
                $args['meta_key'] = '';
                $args['orderby'] = 'name';
                break;
        }
    }
    return $args;
}

/**
 *  Lets add the created sorting order to the dropdown list.
 *  Refrence: http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_catalog_orderby/
 */
//To under Default Product Sorting in Dashboard > WooCommerce > Settings > Products > Display.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby_options', 'wh_catalog_orderby' );
add_filter('woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'wh_catalog_orderby');
function wh_catalog_orderby($sortby) {
    if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE && ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='uk'){

    }else{
        $sortby['name-asc'] = __( 'Sort by name: A - Z', 'us' );
        $sortby['name-desc'] = __( 'Sort by name: Z - A', 'us' );
    }
    return $sortby;
}
```

**P.S.**
28 vw pass b7
62 VW R-LINE S+ 2016
35 VW PASS B7 S+ 13 BLUE
примеры названий. последний сортируется неправильно

Comment: В названии товара `35 tovar name` имеется непечатный символ в самом начале. Отредактируйте название вручную, удалив имеющееся и заново введя нужное.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Сортировка по названию товара происходит не по полю name а по полю title

```
case 'name-asc' :
    $args['order']    = 'ASC';
    $args['meta_key'] = '';
    $args['orderby']  = 'title';
    break;
case 'name-desc' :
    $args['order']    = 'DESC';
    $args['meta_key'] = '';
    $args['orderby']  = 'title';
    break;
```